# Calculating a coordinate from 2 given 1-dimensional lines

Tags: c++, algorithm, navigation, coordinates, positioning

What is the and optimal method, if not the best, for doing it?

Assume that I have an object that has 2 wheels. The only information I have available is how far the wheels have rolled at any time.
[image: Illustration]
Basically, I want to know how to calculate the coordinates (x2,y2)
I put this question on the programming section because I want to solve this with an algorithm or plainly put, by programming (in c++).

Comment: If i've gone 10cm at t = 2s, then the wheel or wheels rolled forward, and backwards if -10. I know how much both wheels roll, and if the algorithm works, then I always know which angle the object is facing and from there calculate a vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have how far the wheels have rolled at any time, it means that you have two functions of time w1(t) w2(t) giving the distance covered by the wheels.
from that you may by derivation get the scalar velocity of each wheel as v1(t) and v2(t).
As your object position is the mean between the position of those two wheels, the velocity of your object is the mean of those two velocities, but the difference of the velocities gives the speed of rotation of the object. So you have essentially a velocity described as a scalar velocity plus a rotation speed.
By integrating that vectorial quantity you may arrive to the current position of your object.

Details must be thought carefully, but the idea I think is that.

Comment: How can I find the speed of rotation?

Comment: Suppose one wheel has velocity v and the other -v then the object doesn't moves just rotates. The angular speed of rotation is given by the speed of 1 wheel divided by the radius and gives radiants per time unit. If you use the difference of speeds (ΔV=v-(-v)=2v then you should divide by the distance between the wheels

Comment: Thanks, but when it stands still and we have v and -v is very easy. But the problem is how to calculate when it's moving while turning.   

E.g.: 
Wheel 1 gives
100
110
120
130
Wheel 2 gives:
100
115
130
140

if it started at (x,y), where is it now?
I can think about finding the arc and then finding a circle and calculate it, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: Well, What you need is V(t)=(dx/dt, dy/dt) in order to compute the current position. But at best you only have sqrt( (dx/dt)^2 + (dy/dt)^2 ) from the traveling distances. So, I don't think you can find the current position with the information given.

Comment: When one wheel has velocity v and the other -v it's easy, but when one has V+v and the other V-v then the movement is forward movement by V and rotation. So in order to find rotation you must take the difference between velocities, and in order to find movement the mean velocity. When you have movement plus rotation than the object is moving rotating so making a circular trajectory.

Comment: Okay, thanks! So basically we got v1 and v2, where the mean is V. V-v1 and V-v2 gives a rotation... then it's calculating that circular trajectory! I'll mark it as an answer because it describes how to find the solution and is not the solution itself.